# C++ wxWidgets: Change Font of Sizer

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I recently started learning C++ and wxWidgets and now I'm building a calculator program. I have a grid sizer with buttons and I want to know is it possible to change the font of the whole sizer instead of changing the font of every single button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sizers are not windows and so don't have any font, so, no, you can't just call `SetFont()` on a sizer. You can iterate over all sizer items and call `SetFont()` on each item which is a window. Or, somewhat less efficiently (because you "waste" a window), but more conveniently, you can make all your button children of a `wxPanel` and associate the existing sizer with this panel. Then you'd be able to call `SetFont()` on the panel, which *is* a window, and so would propagate the font change to all of its children by default.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be to create a child of wxButton that will take the number in constructor and change the font there.